# Printing with a continuous paper on Dot Matrix Printer without page break using JAVA

Tags: java, printing

This is my code to get user's account number and set it to a paper to print.

```
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



/**
 *
 * @author Govinda
 */
public class ChequePrint{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // variable defnations

        String accNum;
        Long cheqNum;
        String solName;
        int qtyCheq;
        String holderName;

        //getting account number from user
        accNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Account Number:", "Cheque Print",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        //setting default values to test
        cheqNum = 12345678912l;
        qtyCheq = 5;
        holderName = "Govinda Thapa";
        solName="Thapathali";

        //generating cheque
        GetCheque newCheque = new GetCheque();

        //setting printing values on cheque

        newCheque.setAccountHolderName(holderName);
        newCheque.setAccountNumber(accNum);
        newCheque.setNumberOfCheque(qtyCheq);
        newCheque.setChequeNumber(cheqNum);
        newCheque.setBranchName(solName);



        //Now setting paper and printer job
        Double width = 8.5 * 72.0;
        Double height =  4.5 * 72.0 * qtyCheq;
        double margin = 0;
        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setSize(width, height);
        paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, width - (margin * 2), height - (margin * 2));
        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, width, height);
        PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
        //Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
        pf.setPaper(paper);
        pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(newCheque,pf);

        try {
            job.print();
        }
        catch(PrinterException pe) {
            System.out.println("error Occured" + pe.getMessage());
        }



    }

}
```

This is my print function that print the required number of cheque.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Govinda
 */
public class GetCheque implements Printable{

    // variable defnations
    //
    private String accountNumber;
    private long chequeNumber;
    private String branchName;
    private int numberOfCheque;
    private String accountHolderName;

    public GetCheque(){

        /*    this.accountHolderName="";
        this.accountNumber="";
        this.branchName="";
        this.numberOfCheque=0;
        this.chequeNumber=0l;*/


    }
    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public long getChequeNumber() {
        return chequeNumber;
    }

    public void setChequeNumber(long chequeNumber) {
        this.chequeNumber = chequeNumber;
    }

    public String getBranchName() {
        return branchName;
    }

    public void setBranchName(String branchName) {
        this.branchName = branchName;
    }

    public int getNumberOfCheque() {
        return numberOfCheque;
    }

    public void setNumberOfCheque(int numberOfCheque) {
        this.numberOfCheque = numberOfCheque;
    }

    public String getAccountHolderName() {
        return accountHolderName;
    }

    public void setAccountHolderName(String accountHolderName) {
        this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
    }

    //printing preferences
    private double xCoor = 0;
    private double yCoor = 0;
    private double margin = 0.25 * 72.0;
    private double marginX = 0.5 * 72.0;
    private Font mainFont = new Font("Roman PS", Font.PLAIN, 9);    


    // Print method to print 

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

        if(pageIndex > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }


        //graphics.setFont(mainFont);
        //int charHeight = graphics.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

        /*        //graphics.translate(0,0);
        //for(int i=0;i<numberOfCheque;i++) {
        graphics.drawString(String.valueOf(chequeNumber), (int )(xCoor + marginX), (int)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+(4*charHeight);
        yCoor=yCoor+charHeight;
        graphics.drawString(branchName, (int)(xCoor + marginX), (int)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+charHeight;
        graphics.drawString(accountNumber, (int)(xCoor + marginX), (int)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+charHeight;
        graphics.drawString(accountHolderName, (int)(xCoor + marginX), (int)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+(3*charHeight);
        chequeNumber = chequeNumber + 1;

        //}*/


        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g2d.setFont(mainFont);

        int charHeight = g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

        // Perform rendering
        g2d.translate(0f,0f);

        for(int i=0;i<numberOfCheque;i++) {

        g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(chequeNumber), (float)(xCoor + marginX), (float)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+(4*charHeight);
        yCoor=yCoor+charHeight;
        g2d.drawString(branchName, (float)(xCoor + marginX), (float)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+charHeight;
        g2d.drawString(accountNumber, (float)(xCoor + marginX), (float)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+charHeight;
        g2d.drawString(accountHolderName, (float)(xCoor + marginX), (float)(yCoor + margin));
        yCoor=yCoor+(3*charHeight);
        chequeNumber = chequeNumber + 1;

        }

        return 0;
    }


}
```

I set the height of page with relative to the number of cheque I hvae to print. But it did not work. What I have to do to print the desired number of cheque in a continuous paper on DOT Matrix Printer.

This code can print upto 5 cheques normally(print start from half of the page) , but if I set the qtyCheque to higher number like 10 or 15 then it doesn't print at all.

What should I do to start the print from the begining of the paper and set the paper height with the relative to the number of cheques to print?

*Thanks for your answer, but how to write my own printer driver, and     how to install it against its original driver? May I have to  install    it as different component or it can be within my code? I just need to    print text and numbers which should be support backslash characters      like \n, \t etc.  Now can you help me? I already tried the given       options but the problem is variable chequeNumber is increased without    printing and then it will print the content with increased       chequeNumber. So I would like to try your another idea i.e, making       driver for the printer. What should I have to do to make printer       driver for myself? Please explain it in detail if possible.*

*

*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Printing API doesn't handle continuous paper well. You have two choices:

1. Collect all the information for 5 forms and print them all together as a single page.
2. Reduce the page size to a single form and always print 5 of them in sequence (so someone can actually take them out of the printer).

Note that you should always try to print in batches of 5 forms (i.e. the number that is between two perforations). Otherwise, tearing off will be a problem.

If you can't get it to work, then most dot matrix printers accept commands sent via the parallel device. That way, you can write your own printer driver which allows you to print single lines of text (without bothering about pages and such) and send form feeds to move to the next perforation.

**EDIT**

As for writing a printer driver: Unless you need to print fancy, colored graphics, you can get away with a simple "write text mixed with escape codes" to the printer.

Check your printer's manual. There should be a section about [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P) or maybe [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language). For example, sending `"\x1bEHello\x1bF\r\n"` to the printer will print the word "Hello" in bold and then move on to the next line.

Here is a pretty good overview of the common escape sequences: http://whitefiles.org/b1_s/1_free_guides/fg2cd/pgs/c03c_prntr_cds.htm

Comment: I edited the question after your answer, Now can you tell me about writing the driver for my printer to print according to  my need.